# Does a maxed out Prinny pass any stats over when it evolves?

Tags: prinny-research-squad

Is there any reason to level a Prinny to Max level? If it is just going to be evolved into a better Prinny that starts at level 1 it seems like you are just wasting experience. Does it pass along any stats or skills differently when maxed out?

Answer (score 1):

Taken directly from the game's FAQ:

"When you evolve a Prinny, it will return to Lv. 1, but depending on the evolved Prinny the maximum level limit may increase, the stats may increase, or it may be able to use skills. There's plenty of good things!
Once your Prinnies reach a level they can evolve at, you should actively evolve them to strengthen your research squad."

This would suggest that a maxed Prinny will created a stronger evolved Prinny. Though this seems true, it may be of negligible worth, as the FAQ suggests "actively" evolving them once they reach the required level instead of maxing them. In the long run it is probably better to max.

Comment: I am reading that line as just them describing what happens when you evolve. It doesn't directly mention any changes directly related to the previous Prinny's level.